# Contact Form 7 - Select Options transparent

Tags: html, wordpress, css, contact-form-7

I'm trying to make Options from Select Drop down transparent but it just don't.

When I make it black, it stays black.

```
.wpcf7-select option {
    background: black !important;
}
```

If I type `background: transparent !important` it just doesn't work. If I try to change background to background-color, it doesn't work.

So I can only change colors, but can't set it up to transparent. Why does it happen?

I've already tried to make transparent by changing opacity and setting background by using RGA and RGBA but it doesn't work as expected

```
.wpcf7-select option {
    /* default fallback */
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255) !important;
    /* nice browsers */
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8) !important;
    /* IE 6/7 */
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#CCFFFFFF, endColorstr=#CCFFFFFF) !important;
    /* IE8 */    
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#CCFFFFFF, endColorstr=#CCFFFFFF)" !important;
}
```

Comment: You are only setting background to transparent for the option elements - likely the select element itself has a background set, too - if only by the user agent stylesheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately with pure CSS make the options part transparent isn't possible. You could however use a JS library to make a custom drop down and style that accordingly.

Comment: But is that possible to make that while using Wordpress and Contact Form 7 plugin?

Comment: Yes, as most custom select menu's merely emulate the actual select box. So updating the custom select, "updates" the invisible actual select.